# Change opacity and add thumbnail on hover using css

Tags: html, css

I would like to change the opacity of the img and add a 50x50 thumbnail for zoom on hover using only CSS no jquery. This is what I have done so far.

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="span4"> 
    <a class="zoom-icon" href="#">
        <img class="blackout image-1" alt="Elite Sports" src="http://www.domain.com/images/es.jpg" width="300" height="300">
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS code:**

```
.span4 { margin: 35px 50px; border: 5px solid #000; }
.span4:hover { border: 5px solid #ccc; }
.span4 a:hover { background: #000; }
.blackout:hover { opacity: .0; }
```

I have the black background on hover working but I can't figure out how to make the thumbnail show up over top of the black background "blackout".  Any helpful tips would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE w/Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/8BMYH/

Comment: Where's the thumbnail?

Comment: In general it can be any thumbnail.  I have it as a magnifying glass 50x50 attached to the link.  The class I have it as is zoom-icon but I think I am doing it wrong because everytime I try it just forgets about the black background.  I am lost at this point.

Comment: Where's the zoom icon? And what do you mean by "attached to the link"? Your code clearly does not show this.

Comment: I know because I removed it.  The only thing I need help with is adding the thumbnail.  I figured if I left it out showing what I have accomplished it would be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/8BMYH/14/

HTML

```
    <div class="span4"> <a class="portfolio-link-icon" href="http://www.elitesports.com"><
        <img class="alignnone blackout size-full wp-image-2592" alt="Elite Sports" src="http://www.surgicalgeeks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/es.jpg" width="300" height="300" />
        <img class="zoom-link" src="http://www.surgicalgeeks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/portfolio-link-icon.png" />
    </a>

</div>
```

CSS

```
span4 {
    background: #000;
    margin: 35px 50px;
    width: 300px !important;
    height: 300px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    float: left;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
}
.span4:hover {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid #8b8c8d;
    border-radius: 25%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(290deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(290deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(290deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(290deg);
    transform: rotate(290deg);
}
.blackout:hover {
    opacity: .0;
}
.zoom-link {
    top: 130px;
    left: 130px;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.span4:hover .zoom-link {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: visible;
}
.span4:hover .blackout {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it with the setup I have currently and not add another img?  The reason I ask is I am using wordpress so I would have to edit a lot more.  << Nevermind no I wouldn't.

Comment: well if only css you could try something like negative z-index on the img tag and zoom icon as a background of the anchor but I dunno, you need to test it

Comment: I will test your solution and get back to you.

Comment: put it in a fiddle so everyone can try it

Comment: I made this, did you want the icon thing to show up on top of the big image on hover? http://jsfiddle.net/TezTj/ or something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/TezTj/1/

Comment: I updated my question.  This is how it looks still can't get it to work though I know I am not the best coder but here it is :) http://jsfiddle.net/8BMYH/

Comment: Basically everything is correct except getting that to thumbnail to show up in the center of the box on hover.

Comment: Take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/8BMYH/1/ I think you should be able to figure out what's going. I took out overflow hidden on span4. Here is another example http://jsfiddle.net/8BMYH/2/ Since your span4 i spinning you need to take the icon out of span4 for it to stay put at a given location. This will involve restructuring the html

Comment: This almost works but when you hover over the zoom-image it makes the black background disappear.

Comment: updated fiddle in answer. you should be able to get it to what you want with it from here

Comment: Yeah that's about what I had I updated mine http://jsfiddle.net/8BMYH/12/ except for still when hovering over the zoom image it takes away the black background.  I need it to stay black.

Comment: that's an easy fix http://jsfiddle.net/8BMYH/14/ anyway I am heading home, best of luck to you

Answer (score 0):

You can add the thumbnail when you hover over the link using the `:after` pseudo-element.  I created a Pen that demonstrates this: http://codepen.io/Ghodmode/pen/xFmqf

This isn't an ideal solution, but it is entirely CSS.  It would be better if I could get the value of the src attribute from the image and use that as the background url using the `attr()` (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#attr) CSS function, but I couldn't get that to work.

```
.span4 a.zoom-icon {
    position: relative;
}

.span4 a.zoom-icon:hover:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    background-image: url("http://bit.ly/XioiVs");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
       -moz-background-size: contain;
         -o-background-size: contain;
            background-size: contain;
}
```